# Does Kurento support video UlpFEC or FlexFEC encoding in RTP Receiver?

Tags: kurento

I have a video media stream from ffmpeg to Kurento RTP Receiver. I have only one client will watch this stream. Question: Does Kurento support Forward Error Correction for video stream? If so, which standard (UlpFEC, FlexFec,...) and does Kurento client support decoding these fec packets?

I didn't find any information in the documentation.